# Converting a while loop into a function? Python

Tags: function, while-loop, python-2.7

In order to condense my code I am trying to make one of my while loops into a function. I have tried numerous times and have yet to receive the same result upon compiling as I would just leaving the while loop.

Here's the while loop:

```
while True:
    i = find_lowest_i(logs)
    if i == -1:
        break
    print "i=", i
    tpl = logs[i].pop(0)
    print tpl
    out.append(tpl)
    print out
```

And here's what I have so far for my function:

```
def mergesort(list_of_logs):
    i = find_lowest_i(logs)
    out = []
    while True:
        if i == -1:
            break
        print "i=", i
        tpl = logs[i].pop(0)
        print tpl
        out.append(tpl)
        print out
    return out
```

Thanks in advance. This place is a safe-haven for a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the parameter to your function is `list_of_logs` and you're still using `logs` inside the function's body. The simplest fix is probably to rename your parameter to `mergesort` from `list_of_logs` to `logs`. Otherwise, looks completely correct to me.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't catch that.